# ARM LXC Container template

Tags: arm, lxc, segmentation-fault, raspbian, container

I've been trying to run LXC on an ARM architecture (arm6l - Raspberry Pi) but with no luck. After some research, I found that maybe trying to run a x86 template on my ARM was causing the problem (bash causing segfault).

Anyone knows where to find container templates for ARM?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem after creating a wheezy tree using [`debootstrap`](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap). Forcing `debootstrap` to bootstrap using the `armhf` architecture using the `--foreign` flag seems like the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the initial container you'll have to goto the new chroot and strap your arm based image manually. Once you have create that you should be able to create a snapshot and clone from the snapshot.